# I am unable to move object in object mode, reinstalled/restarted blender but only the pivot point is moving not object. i don't know why?

Tags: modeling

Blender error: when i installed blender first time, i used transform tools (move/scale/rotate) but the problem is only the pivot point is moving in object mode i can't move overall object in it. In Edit mode i can move all(vertex/edge/face). i don't know How to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably have *Affect Only Origins* enabled. Disable it by pressing *Options* in the top right corner of the 3D viewport > *Origins*

[image]

You can also disable it by pressing the *Active Tool and Workspace Settings* tab in the Properties bar, and press *Origins*.

[image]

Comment: No Origins is not selected in transform section. But now when i check origins on and move then origin and object both moves in opposite directions.

Comment: How about sharing your file so that someone can take a look at your settings?  https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Yes of course, i shared my blender file. Thanks hope someone look at this.

Comment: you need to share the link  ;)

Comment: Click here https://blend-exchange.com and follow instructions