# Cannot Move Object, Can anyone tell what it is?

Tags: particles, transforms, origin

[image]

I'm pretty new to Blender, and was creating grass for landscape. I used the Particle Systems, and after using it, I'm having these coordinates(origin) come up. When I'm trying to move an object, only these are moving and not the object. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.) It is hard to tell from your screen shot what is going on.

Comment: @MartyFouts It's really not necessary to always ask for a file, it takes up space and a statement similar to 'only the origins are moving' gives a quite clear idea what might be the issue. Sorry, not wanting to be rude, but I see those file requests very often and very soon after a question is asked, but often no file is needed. In this case for example it is a setting that's not really dependent on special issues with this exact scene.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219057/i-am-unable-to-move-object-in-object-mode-reinstalled-restarted-blender-but-onl

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I only ask for a file when I think it will help me answer the question, as I did in this case.  You've seen too many questions where the file wasn't needed. I've seen too many answers that had nothing to do with the actual problem, which would have been obvious if the person answering had seen the file.  Better to err on the side of caution; especially when space is a non-issue due to the blend-exchange server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've enabled the *Affect Only Origins* option, which allows you to move the origin of the object (but not the objects, as long as it is enabled), so just deactivate it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked.