# Cannot move object, only origin moves. Does anyone know why?

Tags: modeling, transforms

When I try to move cube in object mode only the origin moves. I can move the cube in edit mode, but the origin doesn't move. The camera and light move fine, it's only the meshes I put in the scene that do not move. I found another post with the same issue and there wasn't an answer. [I am unable to move object in object mode, reinstalled/restarted blender but only the pivot point is moving not object. i don't know why?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219057/i-am-unable-to-move-object-in-object-mode-reinstalled-restarted-blender-but-onl)
If anyone has any idea what the issue is that would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer, but I do appreciate you having the foresight to show the unchecked "Affect Only" boxes in your image. Does this happen with any new file?

Comment: I looked at a lot of questions people had already asked and that was their issue most of the time, just wanted to make it clear that was not what was happening.                     Yes, anytime I open a new file I get the same issue.

Comment: It may be a graphics card problem. If you go into edit mode and back, does it update the mesh ?

Comment: Yeah, I can find a bunch of questions to the same affect too, and most of them are unanswered except for the "Affect Only" ones. Barring anything else, when was the last time you updated your GPU drivers?

Comment: Yes, if I move the mesh in edit mode and go back to object mode the mesh is moved to the new position. The origin does not move though, for some reason. Could be a graphics issue.

Comment: Blender is running on a VM at my work and I don't have access to the last time they updated the graphics drivers. They tend to update things regularly though.

Comment: Yeah, that's hard to tell then - problems can be caused by both too old _and_ too new graphics drivers. For an example, an AMD driver update around February this year messed up viewport visibility for a non-insignificant number of blender users (using AMD GPU's). I do suspect, as Gorgious does, that it may be GPU related, however the fact that it's running on a VM introduces a whole new layer of "moving parts" that can break, and therefore a whole lot more possibilities as to what may be going on. Any additional system specifications you are able to post (if possible) would be helpful.

Comment: Agreed, and hence very difficult to reproduce. But anyways this should be viewed as a bug and reported in the official bug tracker with as much info as possible https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about the specifications. I will have to contact our admin and see if he can tell me anything about our updates and system or figure out the issue.

Comment: It must be some kind of system(graphics) issue, I have multiple VMs and they all have the same issue, so it can't be some setting I messed up.